# PHP fopen: Does data transfer through middle server?

Tags: php, fopen

I have a question about PHP's fopen() function (using "php://output").
Server A uses this fopen() function in order to stream a file from Server B to the user's computer (I have all the necessary header() functions set up to force a download).
My question is: Will the file be streamed *through* Server A, therefore using Server A's bandwidth resources? Or will only Server B's bandwidth be used? I want the streamed file to *not* use Server A's bandwidth resources, only Server B's.
 Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but won't this always use both if these are separate machines? One server has the file and must therefore use consume "up" bandwidth, and the other must download the file and therefore use "down" bandwidth. If server A proceeds to upload the file to a client, then only server A will be hit, but it will have already imposed bandwidth costs to both machines... so for a 1MB file:

Server A: 1MB down + 1MB up
Server B: 1MB up

Answer (score 4):

Server B will use upload bandwidth (to send the file to server A).
Server A will use download bandwidth (to receive the file from server A), and upload bandwidth (to send the file to the user).

If you own both server A and server B, they're dedicated and are provided by the same hosting company, they usually let you buy an internal switch that will connect these two machines on the same internal network. This way the servers' resources are still going to be used, but you won't be charged for internal transfers.

Keep in mind that transferring data from one machine to another will always use bandwidth. It's only a matter of paying more or not.

Answer (score 1):

Server A will be used. `fopen()` operates entirely on the server side and delivers the result to the client, so the client will not know anything about server B.

If you want to use only Server B's resources, you will need to set up a web server on Server B to serve the request, and simply use Server A to point to the resource on Server B.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of any way to transfer a file from Server B to the user without using Server A upload bandwidth? Note: I cannot use a direct link to Server B as this is not provided - I must log in to the server first.

Comment: @hope: if you can't directly connect to serverB, there is no way to avoid having a proxy server (A) and consume both upload AND download bandwidth.